# 2nd and 3rd conditionals

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If I had that book, I would give it to you.

I don't have the book, but if I did have it, I would give it to you.

> If I had had that book, I would have given it to you.

I didn't have the book, but if I had the book, I would've given it to you.

Are both the interpretations correct?

Comment: Both are correct.

Comment: The first may also refer to a past habitual action: "On many occasions when we were students together you asked me for a book, and on each occasion, if I had that book I would give it to you." Ambiguities of this sort are generally ignored in teaching the 'n-conditionals', which is one reason many of us deplore this pedagogic categorization.

Comment: @StoneyB If there is one thing in the English language that I would eliminate if I were granted magical powers, it is the necessity, in certain narrowly defined circumstances, of using the construction "had had."

Comment: @P.E.Dant 1) I don't think *had had* is necessary in OP's second example. 2) *Had had* is eroding. What folks actually **say** is *'d had*, and they're drifting toward *'da had*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doubts with second and third conditional](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52261/doubts-with-second-and-third-conditional)

Answer (score 1):

What seems confusing to me about the 3d Conditional sentence is that the "interpretation" is the same sentence without the double use of "had":

> If I had had that book, I would have given it to you.
>
> If I had the book, I would have given it to you.

Whether the use of the double "had" with a non-action verb, which "have" is here, in a 3d Conditional sentence correct, is another question.

Nevertheless, here is an example of the use of the double "had" when "have" is an action verb:

> He has already had a drink, so he can't drive her home. (That's why
>   she's going to order a taxi.)
>
> If he hadn't had a drink, he could have driven her home. (That's why
>   she got home by taxi.)

Also, [see here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-are-double-words-ok).